# Parse html table data from DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, dom, domxpath

I am scraping data from an external html table that is 100 rows by 3 columns. I want to parse the data into a 10x10 table where the data from each row is combined. Ex:

```
<tr>
    <td>info1</td>
    <td>info2</td>
    <td>info3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>info4</td>
    <td>info5</td>
    <td>info6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>info7</td>
    <td>info8</td>
    <td>info9</td>
</tr>
...and so on
```

into

```
<tr>
   <td>info1<br/>info2<br/>info3</td>
   <td>info4<br/>info5<br/>info6</td>
   <td>info7<br/>info8<br/>info9</td>
   ...7 more times
</tr>
...9 more times
```

I can output the data into a single column by using line breaks. I have absolutely no idea to do what I want to do above. Also I want to be able to style the data using css. Any help/direction is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

  xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $table = $xpath->query('//table[@id="idTable"]')->item(0);
  $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

  foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $cells = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td');
      foreach ($cells as $cell) print $cell->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? If you want a new table to be output, YOU have to output the scaffolding for that table. Right now you're just dumping out the raw data, without so much as a `<table>`, `<tr>` or `<td>` to be seen in the output.

Comment: @MarcB well my problem is visually creating that scaffold for a specific 25x25 table with the three criteria in each cell and printing it from the for loop.

Comment: your xpath should be `$table->getElementsByTagName('td')`. you'll get the individual tds in the order they're definned in the html, and then it's trivial to loop over them and stuff them into your new table. Since you don't care what rows they're in, you can totally ignore the rows in the original table. just focus on the tds.

Comment: You have only 100 rows, if you want to transform it into a 25 columns table by transforming each row into one cell, that should only have 4 rows, not 25 rows.

Comment: @Passerby sorry you are right, Im not sure what I was thinking and edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two (similar) ways you can do this:

1) By counting the `<tr>`s and combine each 10 of them, disregard its `<td>` number:

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($doc);
echo "<table>\n";
/* 10 is the row count */
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    /* 10 is the column count */
    foreach($xpath->query('//table[@id="myTable"]/tr[position()>'.($i*10).' and position()<'.(($i+1)*10+1).']') as $tr)
    {
        echo "\t<td>";// "\t" to make it look nice
        $tds=array();
        foreach($tr->childNodes as $td)
        {
            if($td->nodeName!="td") continue;
            $tds[]=$td->firstChild->nodeValue;
        }
        echo implode("<br />",$tds);
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/lrOLg)

2) By counting the `<td>`s and combine each 3 of them into a new `<td>`, combine each 30 of them into a new `<tr>`, disregard the `<tr>`s:

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($doc);
echo "<table>\n";
$i=0;
$tds=array();
foreach($xpath->query('//table[@id="myTable"]/tr/td/text()') as $td)
{
    /* 30 is each row's old-cell-count */
    if($i%30==0) echo "<tr>\n";
    $tds[]=$td->nodeValue;
    /* 3 is each cell's old-cell-count */
    if($i%3==2)
    {
        echo "\t<td>".implode("<br />",$tds)."</td>\n";
        $tds=array();
    }
    if($i%30==29) echo "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/BncaL)

Both outputs:

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>info0.1<br />info0.2<br />info0.3</td>
    <td>info1.1<br />info1.2<br />info1.3</td>
    <td>info2.1<br />info2.2<br />info2.3</td>
    <td>info3.1<br />info3.2<br />info3.3</td>
    <td>info4.1<br />info4.2<br />info4.3</td>
    <td>info5.1<br />info5.2<br />info5.3</td>
    <td>info6.1<br />info6.2<br />info6.3</td>
    <td>info7.1<br />info7.2<br />info7.3</td>
    <td>info8.1<br />info8.2<br />info8.3</td>
    <td>info9.1<br />info9.2<br />info9.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>info10.1<br />info10.2<br />info10.3</td>
    <td>info11.1<br />info11.2<br />info11.3</td>
<!-- ... -->
    <td>info97.1<br />info97.2<br />info97.3</td>
    <td>info98.1<br />info98.2<br />info98.3</td>
    <td>info99.1<br />info99.2<br />info99.3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I went ahead and used the 2nd option and it worked out great, THANKS